# TO_NUMBER - returning $

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I'm having trouble understanding why the following queries return the given results.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('$1,000.95', '$999,999.999')
FROM dual;
```

returns `1000.95`.

Why doesn't this query return `$1000.95` or `$1,000.95`? Does the `TO_NUMBER` function remove all formatting (other than `.`)?

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('1,000.95', '$999,999.999')
FROM dual;
```

returns `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

I suppose I understand this one a *little* better - the format mask doesn't match the number format. Is there a way to return a `$` in the number (other than using `CONCAT` or `||`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function TO_NUMBER returns a number, the $ character is ASCII and is never going to be represented in a number field. To add a $ character you will need to represent the number as a string.

Comment: Thanks - very clear. Are the only possible characters available in numbers `.` and `-`, or are there others?

Comment: well that also depends on how the number is being presented to you by you OS or software and can be effected by local/currency/etc settings, it is not stored like that by the DB

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT TO_NUMBER('$1,000.95', 'L999G999D999') FROM dual;
```